# Search form not working with custom query?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, loop

My search query doesn't seem to work, the query in my url is all correct but the content just refreshes without finding the posts with the search term..

I got a custom search query and a function to only search for words in the title.

Heres my index.php:
http://pastebin.com/8CPWy3Ye

Heres my search filter function function.php:
http://pastebin.com/uyUPT9jR

If I remove my custom query it all seems to work, I don't know if it's because my search form can't fetch the parameters in my custom post query?

all help appreciated :)

the search query works without my custom query:
Normal while:
`<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>`

But I want it to work my custom while:
`<?php if ($movies->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($movies->have_posts()) : $movies->the_post(); ?>`

I tested if the function had anything to do with the custom query.. It hadnt, so it might be the form that need to be found in my custom query?

Comment: I hope anyone of you can help me!